# Is there a short way to specify a list of attribute names and how they are to be transformed in similar way?

Tags: xslt

Following XSLT defines a transformation of an XML into CSV format:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />
<xsl:template match="myList">
    <xsl:text>"a","b","c","d","e","f","g"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="myTag">
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@a"/><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@b"/><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@c"/><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@d"/><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@e"/><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@f"/><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@g"/><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Writing up the value extraction manually for each attribute is tiresome and makes code size increase as the nuber of attributes increase. Is there a way to shorten it, so that I specify the list of the fields and their order in a single place("a","b","c","d","e","f","g") and then specify some kind of shorter pattern that specifies that the attributes are to be extracted and formatted like they are? If it makes things easier, maybe make an exception and perform this manually for the last attribute `@g`, since it is different in that it doesn't require a comma after it.

Comment: Are you restricted to XSLT 1.0? And if you are, are the attribute names really `a`, `b`, `c` etc. so that you could process `@*` and sort by name?

Comment: I'd prefer answers for both versions. The attributes need to be exactly matched, because there could be other stuff in the XML or they could be in different order than required by output CSV.

Comment: Attributes in the XSLT/XPath data model are not ordered so you need to tell us whether the used example order (alphabetic) could be used to process `@*` in alphabetic order.

Comment: It's also crucial to know if an attribute can be missing.

Comment: @MartinHonnen assume that the order cannot be derived programmatically, it needs to be specified.

Comment: @michael.hor257k If an attribute is missing you just put empty quotes, that's the behaviour of the code I posted.

Comment: Yes, but you are asking for a different approach. If an attribute can be missing, then a different approach is not really possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
<xsl:template match="@*" mode="m">
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>",</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

and then (in XSLT 2.0)

```
<xsl:for-each select="myTag">
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g" mode="m"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or in XSLT 1.0 (though I can no longer envisage any circumstances in which I would use XSLT 1.0...)

```
<xsl:for-each select="myTag">
   <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@a" mode="m"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@b" mode="m"/>
   ....
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 2.0 or later you could use

```
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="@a, @b, @c, @d, @e, @f, @g" separator="&quot;,&quot;"/>
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
```

If attributes can be missing then I think you would need to wrap each `@foo` into `string(@foo)`, i.e.

```
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="string(@a), string(@b), string(@c), string(@d), string(@e), string(@f), string(@g)" separator="&quot;,&quot;"/>
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
```